# Passing a global string variable between .cpp files?

Tags: c++, string, function

I have created a globals.h header file which has the extern string which is declared as "new_name". In image_output.cpp (main), I have declared string(new_name) as a global variable at the top of my function. Then I passed that variable into the erode_image.cpp(function file) and update it. I have included the globals.h with the main and the function files. The problem is that the "new_name" variable does not get updated in the function file(erode_image.cpp). Does anyone know where I am doing mistake?

globals.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

extern string new_name;
```

erode_image.cpp (function):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "functions.h"
#include "globals.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


Mat erode_image(Mat image, int erosion_size, string new_name) {

    new_name += "_eroded";
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(erosion_size, erosion_size));
    erode(image, image, element);

    return image;

}
```

image_output.cpp (main):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "functions.h"
#include "globals.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat imgCrop;
string new_name;

int erosion_size = 25;
int dilate_size = 50;
int brightness = 50;
int threshold_to_zero = 3;
int sectionCount = 5;

int main()
{

    String folderpath = "*.png";
    vector<String> filenames;
    cv::glob(folderpath, filenames);

    //removes ./ from beginning of filepath
    for (int i = 0; i < size(filenames); i++) {
        filenames[i] = filenames[i].erase(0, 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size(filenames); i++) {
        if (filenames[i].find("_cropped") == string::npos) {


            string image_path = filenames[i];
            string new_name = image_path.substr(0, image_path.find_last_of('.')) + "_cropped";
            string extension = image_path.substr(image_path.find_last_of("."));
            Mat img = imread(image_path);
            cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

            img = crop_image(img);
            img = rotate_image(img);
            img = erode_image(img, erosion_size, new_name);
            //img = average_section_threshold(img, sectionCount, new_name);
            //img = dilate_image(img, dilate_size, new_name);

            string new_file_name = new_name + extension;
            imwrite(new_file_name, img);
            cout << "Image Succesfully Saved!";


            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're updating the local variable (parameter) called `new_name`, not the global variable.

Comment: Better would be to avoid global variables completely.  Declare it locally in `main` then pass it by reference to `new_name` for modification.  If for some reason you must use the global variable, do not declare it at all (either as a parameter or other local variable) within `new_name`, as this creates a new variable that shadows the global.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. For any future youngling C++ coders that land on this post 1) Delete the globals.h file 2) define string locally in your main .cpp file 3) pass function the variable in main 4) change your function to access the memory location of the variable (Mat erode_image(Mat image, int erosion_size, string &new_name); as shown 5) update variable inside of function new_name += "_eroded";

Comment: If you care about _For any future youngling C++ coders that land on this post_ (which is not a bad concern), please, write a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Will do in future

Answer (score 0):

You already solved your problem in the comments, so I'm just typing it up to make it a proper answer.

Your original code was like this:

globals.h

```
extern std::string new_name;
```

other_file.cpp

```
#include "globals.h"

void func(std::string new_name)  // <- shadows the global new_name
{
    new_name += "_stuff";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "globals.h"
std::string new_name;

int main()
{
    new_name = "bla";
    func(new_name);

    std::cout << new_name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here `new_name` in `main` is not updated, and the output is `bla`. This happens because the argument in `func` shadows the global/extern variable.

The correct way to use `extern` (if you *really* want to keep the global) is to remove the argument to `func`:

globals.h

```
extern std::string new_name;
```

other_file.cpp

```
#include "globals.h"

void func()
{
    new_name += "_stuff";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "globals.h"
std::string new_name;

int main()
{
    new_name = "bla";
    func();

    std::cout << new_name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the shadowing is gone, and the output is `bla_stuff`. However, this uses a global which is something to avoid, since being global makes it hard to reason about where, when, and how the variable is updated (as it can be accessed literally anywhere in the program).

A better solution is to get rid of the global, and instead pass the variable like originally except by reference.

other_file.cpp

```
void func(std::string& new_name)
{
    new_name += "_stuff";
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    std::string new_name = "bla";
    func(new_name);

    std::cout << new_name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the global is gone (as is the `globals.h` file), and the output is still `bla_stuff` as intended.